# params[] in TSQL procedure?

Tags: sql-server, arrays, t-sql, procedure, parameters

Can I force the procedure to use array of parameters?

Something similar to `Console.WriteLine(String msg, params[])` in C#

I need it to pass column names of table in procedure, something similar to `INSERT INTO` operation, but need to pass *n* arguments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I send array of parameter to store procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961166/can-i-send-array-of-parameter-to-store-procedure)

Comment: Yeah but this is working like string parsing, what about CLR-UDF functions?

Comment: You can use a table-valued parameter. But more generally, there are several questions on Stack Overflow that already address this pattern.

Comment: `<shamelessplug>`[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19957857/1362136) is an example of using a table-valued parameter `</shamelessplug>`

Answer (score 1):

As said above, a Table Valued Parameter is probably your best option here.

I've also had some success with XML parameters (might be easier to generate from C#, depending on the host), and allows some more complexity on the parameter side.

Before SQL 2008, I used pipe (|) separated strings and a string splitter function, which also work fine.

Comment: [Erland Sommarskog wrote an excellent reference on TVPs](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) which covers the use case of arrays and lists in SQL Server. Really good resource for anyone who's not used them before.